# Convert list of dictionaries saved in txt file into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file that is basically a list of multiple python dictionaries.
The text file look as follows

```py
[{"ques": ["What can cause skidding on bends?"], "options": [{"option": "This opt no1", "correct": true, "number": 1}, {"option": "this opt no.2", "correct": true, "number": 2}, {"option": "[| this is opt3", "correct": false, "number": 3}], "indx": "2.1.01-001"},
{"ques": ["What can cause a dangerous situation?"], "options": [{"option": "option1", "correct": true, "number": 1}, {"option": "opt2", "correct": true, "number": 2}], "indx": "2.1.01-004"}]
```

**What I want to do?**

I want to convert the dictionaries into pandas data frame systematically:

**What doesn't work?**

```
import json
with open('\questions_dict.txt') as json_file:
    data=json.load(json_file)
    df_ques = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    print(df_ques)
```

**Desired output**

```
indx       ques                muliple_option    correct
2.1.1.1   this is question    option no1           True
2.1.1.1   NAN                 option no2           True
2.1.1.1   NAN                 option no3           False
2.1.1.2   2nd  is question    option no1           True
2.1.1.2   NAN                 option no2           False
2.1.1.2   NAN                 option no3           False
and so one ..................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explode` and `apply` `pd.json_normalize`

```
result = (
df_ques.explode("ques")
       .explode("options")
       .groupby(['ques', 'indx'])['options']
       .apply(pd.json_normalize)
       .reset_index()
       .drop(columns=['level_2', 'number'])
)
result
```

output:

```
    ques                                    indx        option          correct
0   What can cause a dangerous situation?   2.1.01-004  option1         True
1   What can cause a dangerous situation?   2.1.01-004  opt2            True
2   What can cause skidding on bends?       2.1.01-001  This opt no1    True
3   What can cause skidding on bends?       2.1.01-001  this opt no.2   True
4   What can cause skidding on bends?       2.1.01-001  [| this is opt3 False
```

---

Or just use `json_normalize` to parse json data.

```py
data_str = '''
[{"ques": ["What can cause skidding on bends?"], "options": [{"option": "This opt no1", "correct": true, "number": 1}, {"option": "this opt no.2", "correct": true, "number": 2}, {"option": "[| this is opt3", "correct": false, "number": 3}], "indx": "2.1.01-001"},
{"ques": ["What can cause a dangerous situation?"], "options": [{"option": "option1", "correct": true, "number": 1}, {"option": "opt2", "correct": true, "number": 2}], "indx": "2.1.01-004"}]
'''
data=json.loads(data_str)
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['options'], meta=['indx', 'ques'])
print(df)
```

```
            option  correct  number        indx  \
0     This opt no1     True       1  2.1.01-001   
1    this opt no.2     True       2  2.1.01-001   
2  [| this is opt3    False       3  2.1.01-001   
3          option1     True       1  2.1.01-004   
4             opt2     True       2  2.1.01-004   

                                    ques  
0      What can cause skidding on bends?  
1      What can cause skidding on bends?  
2      What can cause skidding on bends?  
3  What can cause a dangerous situation?  
4  What can cause a dangerous situation?
```

Comment: Thank  @Ferris. I accept his suggestion, it is more convenient to just use `json_normalize` on the original data.

Answer (score 2):

You have to flatten the dict and index all the data-points.
[image]

Here is the required code:

```py
data  = [{"ques": ["What can cause skidding on bends?"], "options": [{"option": "This opt no1", "correct": True, "number": 1}, {"option": "this opt no.2", "correct": True, "number": 2}, {"option": "[| this is opt3", "correct": False, "number": 3}], "indx": "2.1.01-001"},
{"ques": ["What can cause a dangerous situation?"], "options": [{"option": "option1", "correct": True, "number": 1}, {"option": "opt2", "correct": True, "number": 2}], "indx": "2.1.01-004"}]

s = []
for row in data:
    question = row.get('ques')[0]
    idx = row.get('indx')
    for option in row.get("options", []):
        number = option.get("number", np.nan)
        number = f"This is option {number}" #edit
        correct = option.get("correct", np.nan)
        s.append(dict(question = question, 
                      number = number, 
                      correct = correct,
                      index = idx))
    

df = pd.DataFrame(s)
df
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible for you to add the code for adding column options to text as well. Like, "This is option no 1 ". I don't need numbers but the text of options.

Comment: see above ;-) @Faisal

Comment: I mean I don't need a column 'number' but the one column with name 'options' that displays text of options for all question like: "This opt no1", this opt no.2. Text not digits(1,2,3,1,2)

Comment: I am not sure I understand as that would be an inconvenient way to store data in a pandas dataframe. Usually data is sliced as needed with the various functions that `pandas` offers. If you want subheaders you could create a series, but that complicates a dataset that does not require it.